# How to select the first N elements of each row in a df column (of arrays)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the values are arrays and I wish to be able to trim down the arrays to the first *n* elements.

If this is my example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3, 3]], 'b': [[6, 7, 8, 9], [6, 6, 9, 9]]})
print(df)
             a             b
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [6, 7, 8, 9]
1  [2, 2, 3, 3]  [6, 6, 9, 9]
```

Then for example, if *n* is 2, this is my desired output:

```
       a       b
0  [1, 2]  [6, 7]
1  [2, 2]  [6, 6]
```

How can I accomplish this? I've seen similar solutions for where the column values are strings, but not arrays.

Comment: FYI. Those are lists, not arrays. And `.str.slice()` works on either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.str[:2]))
```

Prints:

```
        a       b
0  [1, 2]  [6, 7]
1  [2, 2]  [6, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was running into an unrelated issue using the str slicing method but got it working now!